# Shut down after offline updates with PackageKit from command line

Tags: scripting, shutdown, software-updates, packagekit, non-root-user

When [PackageKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackageKit) has updates fetched for installation and you use the Gnome GUI to shut down the machine, it is possible to set a checkbox to install updates before shut down. How can this be accomplished from command line without root? Example purpose: automating the execution of custom commands before shut down.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
# This will force fetching repository data and updates
pkcon get-updates
pkcon update --only-download

dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply \
  --dest=org.freedesktop.PackageKit \
  /org/freedesktop/PackageKit \
  org.freedesktop.PackageKit.Offline.Trigger \
  string:power-off

if pkcon offline-get-prepared; then
  systemctl reboot
else
  systemctl poweroff
fi
```

If you remove the `dbus-send` command and replace the `if` block by `systemctl reboot`, the system will reboot instead.